# Is there a way to call the XKCD api by a comic name someone sumbits insted of a comic number (JS)

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm currently trying to make a slack bot that lets someone get a comic from the XKCD api, and I've made it possible so far for people to get a comic by inputting a number.

Something I want to implement is letting people get a comic by inputting it's name, although AFAIK I can only make a request to the xkcd api with something like this: xkcd.com/(comic_number)/info.0.json

I'm stuck on how to implement names (I don't want to use a search API for this task, like I've seen around)

is there a way I can let people input a name, and get a comic using the API or is there some other solution?

Comment: Is this API documented? Do you have a link to the documentation? I only found this https://xkcd.com/json.html It mentions only two endpoints. I guess the answer to your question is: No, there is no API endpoint to find a comic by title.

Comment: Yeah, this is the API. Is there something else I can implement in order to allow people to input a comic name, and get an output?

Comment: Yes, but you don't want to use a search API. You could also search on the client. That means, iterate all comics until you find one with the correct title.

Comment: You can cache all the data or store them in a database for text search.